# Finding source of duplicate mappings in Fluent NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, orm, fluent-nhibernate, mapping

Earlier today, I broke one of my classes into two, by marking the original as abstract, and creating two subclasses that inherit from the abstract base.

I added a line to my FluentNHibernate mapping to discriminate the subclasses based on a column value (table-per-class heirarchy) as follows:

```
DiscriminateSubClassesOnColumn("EntryType");
```

That field is an integer in the database.

My new mappings inherit from

```
SubClassMap<MyChildType>
```

With a new line in the constructor method of MyChildTypeMap for the discriminator as follows:

```
DiscriminatorValue(1);
```

I am continuously running into this exception:

```
"Duplicate class/entity mapping MyNamespace.MyChildObject"
```

In the Fluent NHibernate session builder, (Fluently.Configure()....)  I added the line to export the mappings to hbm files.  Sure enough, the subclass is listed twice in the mapping file of the parent class.

I am not using AutoMapped configurations.
I am using Fluent NHibernate 1.2.0.0
I am using NHibernate 3.2.0.400

I'm at wit's end trying to figure out where this comes from.  Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you ever figured out the root cause of this? I have a similar question on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick way to see how your mappings are constructed is to use FluentNHibernate's diagnostics:

```
Fluently.Configure()
    .Database(\\your db stuff here)
    .Diagnostics(diag => diag.Enable().OutputToConsole())
    .Mappings(\\mappings);
```

This will stream (to your console in this case, you can also `OutputToFile`) a debug log of what mappings are being created from what classes and what caused them to be added or skipped.

Comment: Ah, I was unaware of that one!  Thank you!